# Произношение дат

Tags: числительные

Как правильно сказать:"Участвовал в войне 1787—1791 гг."? Тысяча семьсот восемьдесят седьмого — тысяча семьсот девяносто первого *года* (или *годов*)?

Answer (score 4):

Война длилась несколько лет, значит множественное число, **годов**. Об этом же говорит принятое у историков сокращение *гг.*